# Database Custom Sort Order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sorting

I want to order the role of the members. Like :

```
Leaders 
Co Leaders
Elders
Members
```

But when I use `ORDER BY`, it orders according to the alphabet. That is :

```
Co Leaders
Elders 
Leaders
Members
```

Is it possible to do the sorting like that?

Comment: Add a `weigth` field to your table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to `ORDER` with `FIELD` :

```
ORDER BY FIELD(your_field, 'Leaders' , 'Co Leaders', 'Elders', 'Members')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column as `sort_order int(10) default 0` ;

Now put the value like sort_order = 0 where member_role = Leaders, 1 for Co Leaders and else.

then `ORDER BY sort_order`

Answer (score 0):

Use can also use `Case statement` to custom the order.

```
order by case columnname 
              when 'Leaders' then 1 
              when 'Co Leaders' then 2
              when 'Elders' then 3
              when 'Members' then 4
         End
```

Comment: @Strawberry - sorry didn't get you.

Comment: What advantage does this offer over FIELD()

Comment: @Strawberry This is just another way of doing it nothing wrong in posting another answer.

Comment: I'm not suggesting there is, am I?? Just wanted to know :-(